# accessing related lookup in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl, lookup-filter

Hi I am writing a SOQL query. I use Fuse IT to check my SOQL queries. So the Query is:

`Select Id,Name,Material__r.APS_Account__r.FirstName, Material__r.APS_Account__r.LastName from Material_Order`

In this query the Material Order has a look up to Material and the MAterial has a look up to Account. So i am trying to get FirstName and LastName of Account from Material_Order. The query works but i get the result as
eg resultset for the field
Material__r.APS_Account__r.FirstName = Account Dave Scott(where Dave is the Firstname and Scott is the LastName).
Account keeps appending it for the result
I need to know how to remove the word account from my result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you sure it is not added in name . try to run this query from Developer console.

Comment: Hi Tushaar. I ran it. here it shows the result as [object Object] for the field

Comment: try to debug the record and then Check.

Comment: It showed up properly in the workbench. I don't know why it was showing like that in the fuse extension

Comment: Is this query working fine in the developer console? Or is not working only through Fuse?

Comment: @Dino then i think it is related to FuseIt and you should contact their support.